# How to get a random element from a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, random, module

I want to generate a random  element from a list that is already given by myself or a list taken as an input .

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

l = [3,2,6,1]

random_element = random.choice(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(random.choice(values))
```